# Is it possible to push/pull variables between two instances of R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have two instances of R running.  Are there existing solutions to *easily* send variables/data from one instance to the other?  Maybe even synchronize the values of a variable between the two instances?

For example, first the two instances (R1 & R2) would be connected somehow, then in R1:

```
> a <- 12
> push(a)
```

and at this point in R2:

```
> a
[1] 12
```

The keyword here is ease of use: make it as quick as possible (for the user) to interactively synchronize the value of certain variables.  I would use this with Mathematica's RLink to work interactively in one R instance and push/pull data to/from Mathematica's instance.

---

I realize that the question might sound strange.  The reason why I'm hopeful that something like this exists is that it would be useful for parallel or distributed computing as well (which is not my use case here).

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb (and possibly be wrong) and say this is probably not possible. The clunky solution would be to `save()` data out to disk and then `load()` it back in in the other session, but automatic synchronising, I don't think so. I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: @thelatemail I would be happy with *manual* one-way-at-a-time sync if it's easy enough (i.e. doesn't require typing a long command to synchronize the relevant variables).  How does parallelization work in R?  Does it launch several instances of R and if yes, how do they communicate?

Comment: What's wrong with simply using `serialize` with `socketConnection`? The examples section of `?socketConnection` shows how to use it to communicate between two R processes.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Feel free to post an answer.  It's clear I think that many people (i.e. not only I) do not know about this possibility, so it would be good to have this put in an answer, maybe with a short example if you have time.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I don't have time. The help page already has a short example. Maybe you or someone else can expand it to an answer to your question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have a look at `svSocket`. From the package description at: [svSocket.pdf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/svSocket/svSocket.pdf)

```
The SciViews svSocket package provides a stateful, multi-client and preemtive socket server.  [...] 

Although initially designed to server GUI clients, the R socket server can also be used to exchange data between separate R processes.
```

[This demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvT8XThGA8o) is really worth it.

Comment: That's rather amazing. I'm glad to be proven absolutely totally wrong.

Comment: That video is now 6 years old - I still find it amazing, but can't help thinking there have been enhancements since then :-)  I saw some interesting socket/threading ideas done [in Python by David Beazley](https://youtu.be/MCs5OvhV9S4?t=9m39s) - I don't know how the R processes optimise the workload...

Answer (score 10):

This is a different approach to the push/pull model, but you can use the `bigmemory` package to create a matrix that exists in shared memory (or on disk) that can be accessed across multiple R sessions on the same machine:

**R session 1**

```
library(bigmemory)
m <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
m <- as.big.matrix(m, type="double", backingfile="m.bin", descriptorfile="m.desc")
m
# An object of class "big.matrix"
# Slot "address":
# <pointer: 0x7fba95004ee0>
```

**R session 2**

```
library(bigmemory)
m <- attach.big.matrix("m.desc") 
# Now any changes you make to m will be reflected in both sessions!
```

This is also useful for parallel computing using on matrices, since you're now only passing around the pointer to the matrix to each of the spawned R sessions, rather than the whole 
object.

Since we've created a file-backed big matrix, it also allows you to create matrices it also allows you to create and operate on matrices larger than memory!

**Parallel example**

```
library(bigmemory)
library(doMC) # Windows users will need to choose a different parallel backend
library(foreach)
registerDoMC(4) # number of cores (new R sessions to spawn) to run in parallel.

m <- matrix(rnorm(1000*1000), 1000)
as.big.matrix(m, type="double", backingfile="m.bin", descriptorfile="m.desc")
# Just to make sure we don't have any of these objects in memory when we spawn the 
# parallel sessions
rm(m)
gc()

foreach(i = 1:4) %dopar% {
  m <- attach.big.matrix("m.desc")
  # do something!
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think [Redis](http://redis.io/) can help you achieve what you want. 
You can use the R packages `rredis` and/or `RcppRedis`

On the first instance of R you can do

```
library(rredis)
redisConnect()
redisSet("a", 12)
[1] "OK"
```

Then on the second R  instance you can then do

```
library(rredis)
redisConnect()
redisGet("a")
[1] 12
```

Comment: Looks like a very useful start.  Are you aware of any solutions to eliminate having to type command in *both* instances (e.g. control the second with the first or let the second detect any changes and pull them automatically?  Also, would this work with any R datatype or only those that are explicitly supported by redis?  For example, what about an igraph network?

Comment: @Szabolcs redis is very useful for serialization and to my knowledge you can serialize any type of R object. I just tested an igraph network and it works. Which type of command you want to eliminate ?

Comment: I want to eliminate having to type commands in both instances, if possible.  Maybe I can achieve a middle-way by using a special variable to store the name of all variables that were sent from instance 1.  Then a simple (parameterless) command will automatically retrieve these names in instance 2 and will know what else to `redisGet`.  Then I still have to type commands in both, but I don't have to mention `"a"` two times.

Comment: I think you need the `redisKeys` function to automatically retrieve the differents keys on the server and then feed `redisGet` with these keys. Feel free to read also the vignette: `vignette("rredis", package = "rredis")`

Comment: @Szabolcs It looks like dickoa gave you a great answer, but if you did want to go the Redis route I think you could accomplish your aim via a taskCallbackManager that pops from a list of recent keys (pushed when the other system does its set) and pulls those keys into the local namespace.